# Export to xls using APACHE POI not working in Weblogic under Linux

Tags: weblogic, apache-poi

[image]I have a export to xls functionality which is working fine in windows. When I deploy ear to Linux box, file open with ugly characters.

Data is in a collection and I am iterating through and using POI API to create xls file. Then I am mapping this file to context so that this can be open through application -
**Weblogic.xml**

```
<wls:weblogic-web-app
    xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.2/weblogic-web-app.xsd">
    <wls:weblogic-version>10.3.5</wls:weblogic-version>
    <wls:context-root>ncrone</wls:context-root>
    <wls:virtual-directory-mapping>
        <!-- <wls:local-path>/u501/data/</wls:local-path> --> <!-- THIS IS FOR UNIX -->
        <wls:local-path>C:\\data\\</wls:local-path>
        <wls:url-pattern>*.xls</wls:url-pattern>
        <wls:url-pattern>invoiceExport/*</wls:url-pattern>
    </wls:virtual-directory-mapping>
</wls:weblogic-web-app>
```

In windows when I click on "export to xls" it create xls and open a dialog to ask open or save and in either case I can see correct xls.
In Unix when I click on "export to xls" it create xls and is not opening and dialog box and open xls right away with ugly characters. Is there any solution? So far what I understand UNIX does not support GUI. This might be an issue.
Thanks.

Comment: 1. you are on UNIX or LINUX ? If Linux , there should not be an issue as Linux has a GUI and that GUI supports Open Office meaning you can open XLS files flawlessly

Comment: then you should be able to open and see the excel

Comment: Nope. Its not working.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what isn't working? Such as specific steps taken, code used, what works, what doesn't, what errors, what screenshots etc?

Comment: I think you are trying to cat or vi the xls file. As xls is differently encoded, you need specific software(readers) to open the file (Popularly used readers... MS Office for Windows, Open Office for Linux).

Comment: Looks to me like your browser is trying to display the excel file as if it was plain text. Do you perhaps need to do something in your code to have it sent back correctly as a binary file with the excel mimetype?

Comment: Facing the same issue, specifically on WebLogic. Its working file when I deploy it on JBoss.